# EDEN Framework together with Zend Framework: Cannot redeclare class Eden_Class

Tags: php, zend-framework

Iam trying to integrate EDEN PHP [Link to Page](http://eden.openovate.com/) into my Zend Framework 1.10.x Application. I have moved the Files into the Folder where all other Librarys are located.

In my index.php:

```
/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';
require_once 'eden.php';
```

Application.ini:

```
autoloadernamespaces.6 = "Eden_"
```

When i try to create an instance of an eden Class with:

```
$fbAuth = eden('facebook')->auth('$key','$secret','http://yourwebsite.com/auth');
```

I get the following error?

> Cannot redeclare class Eden_Class in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/page/library/eden/class.php on line 27

Any ideas? (PHP Version 5.3.6)

Comment: Is it possible that eden.php already setup auto loading for that framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (working for me) added this to my Bootstrap.php

```
/**
 * Setup EDEN Framework
 * http://eden.openovate.com/
 * 
 * @return void 
 */
public function _initEden()
{
     eden()->setLoader(false);
}
```